# Tests with Yii 1.x and CodeCeption

Tags: php, yii, codeception

I want to configure Yii 1 with CodeCeption, I followed the instructions but I get an error when to try the functional test

$ codecept run tests/functional/IndexCept.php -vvv

```
  [Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]           
  Module \Helper\Functional could not be found and loaded
```

This is my CodeCeption.yml

```
actor: Dev
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_log
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_helpers
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
    debug: true
modules:
    enabled: [PhpBrowser, WebHelper, TestHelper, Yii1]
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: http://yii1-test.com/
        Yii1:
            appPath: '/web/mercadojobs.com/test.php'
            url: http://yii1-test.com/test.php
```

My functional suite

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Yii1:
            appPath: '/web/mercadojobs.com/test/index.php'
            url: 'http://yii1-test.com/index.php'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Codeception are you using?

Comment: You are mixing up 2 naming schemes of helper classes in your configuration - suffixed WebHelper (used in Codeception 2.0) and namespaced \Helper\Functional (current).  If you are using old test suite and reading current documentation, change \Helper\Functional to  FunctionalHelper.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply, I have 2.2.7 version.